# Linux - environment variables $HOME versus $(HOME)

Tags: linux, environment-variables

Recently I had to update my JAVA environment variable in `.bashrc`

> echo $JAVA_HOME # prints out /usr/java/...
>
> echo $(JAVA_HOME) # raises error "can't find JAVA_HOME command"

I'm worried that my make file, which uses `$(JAVA_HOME)` won't work since `$JAVA_HOME` gets recognized, but not `$(JAVA_HOME)`

How can I get `$(JAVA_HOME)` to equal `$JAVA_HOME`, which is currently set? Also, why does this happen?

thanks

Comment: If I remember well, in makefiles there's no such problem, because the $(WHATEVER) form gets processed by make itself

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`make` is not `bash`

They deal with variables differently. `$foo` is how you read a variable called *foo* in bash, and `$(foo)` is how you read it in a makefile.

Answer (score 5):

More precisely:

- `JAVA_HOME` is a shell variable; assuming it has been exported with `export`, it is then an environment variable.
- `$JAVA_HOME` is the `bash` syntax to expand the shell variable named `JAVA_HOME`.
- In `bash`, `$(command)` substitutes the output of `command` -- so `$(JAVA_HOME)` is trying to run a command called `JAVA_HOME`, hence the error you got.
- When `make` starts up, it looks at each environment variable and sets a `make` variable of the same name to the same value.  (See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Environment .)
- `$(JAVA_HOME)` is the `make` syntax to expand the `make` variable named `JAVA_HOME`.

So your `Makefile` should work just fine: `$(JAVA_HOME)` expands the `make` variable `JAVA_HOME`, which was set to the value of the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` (unless your `Makefile` deliberately did something to override it), which has the right value.

Answer (score 2):

> Q: Will my make file read environment
>   variables then? If I define $JAVA_HOME
>   in .bashrc, will my make file read
>   $(JAVA_HOME) correctly?

A: Yes, absolutely :)

Answer (score 1):

make will set its variables to the environment. (the inverse is not true.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the difference between $JAVA_HOME and $(JAVA_HOME) is simply that make has a different syntax for variables than bash.

Answer (score 1):

... and ${foo} or ${HOME} is allowed too in bash, but, for HOME, seldom needed. It is useful for catenation, because ${HOME}OFFICE will expand to /home/stefanOFFICE on my machine, but I don't need it, while $HOMEOFFICE is completely unknown; $HOME isn't expanded.

$HOME is often concatenated, but with a slash, which is sufficient, to delimit the variable, so ${HOME}/bin and $HOME/bin work both.